# Can I add more countries to Exp:resso Store shipping options?

Tags: expresso-store

What's the best way to add additional countries to the system with Store 2.x? I see a button in the CP to add a new state option to a country, but no control for adding a new country. Is it possible to do without diving into the database and adding records directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store 1 uses EE's internal list of countries at `system/expressionengine/config/countries.php` as Justin mentioned.

Store 2 has its own list of countries at `third_party/store/data/countries.php`. When Store is installed, these are copied into the `exp_store_countries` database table.

So if you're feeling revolutionary, and you have already installed Store, the best option is to simply update the `exp_store_countries` table directly. There is no control panel interface for this, but there's no danger in doing it and your changes won't be overridden with any future upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

Store picks up the countries from the `/system/expressionengine/config/countries.php` file. The countries are stored in an array in that file so you can just add any new countries to that array and they should appear in Store.